# Center TED talk iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, alignment, center

I am looking to embed a Ted talk into my site but would like to center.

The iframe is within multiple div's so I am having a little trouble isolating and coding in the necessary parameters.

Current code:

```html
<div style="max-width:854px"><div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%"><iframe src="https://embed.ted.com/talks/derek_sivers_keep_your_goals_to_yourself" width="854" height="480" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
```

Comment: You need to include the working example which completely replicates the described issue in order to get the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the style `margin: 15%;` for the first div.
Increase or decrease the value based on your requirement